# Rectangle shapefiles with the same extents does not align perfectly after projection

Tags: qgis, arcmap, coordinate-system, ogr

I have a rectangle shapefile built with UTM19 coordinates using a python script, and then projected to NAD83_CSRS (EPSG:4617).

I have a second rectangle shapefile built with the same method (python with UTM19 coords), with the same corners coordinates but gridded with 200m squares. This layer is then also projected in NAD83_CSRS projection (EPSG:4617).

If I load the two layers in their original projection (UTM19), they align perfectly everywhere. But if I load the projected layer, They align perfectly in the corners but there is a shift when you look more in the middle area of the extents (see image). The shift is in the range of 5~8m.

[image]

I tried reprojecting the layers with ArcMap, QGIS and OGR and I always get the same result.

Anyone has an idea what that problem might be and how can I resolve it ?

Comment: You say your original datasets are in UTM 19, but with what datum? NAD 83? WGS 84? NAD 27? If it's not NAD 83 what transformation are you using when you project?

Comment: It may be that conversion from UTM into EPSG:4617 introduces some curvature and line that is straight in UTM is actually curved in EPSG:4617. However, the big rectangle has vertices only in the corners. Try what happens if you add some intermediate vertices into the big polygon before re-projecting it. You can use the -segmentize option of ogr2ogr for that http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html.

Comment: @user30184 You were right on. I projected the rectangle shapefile using a -segmentize value of 200m and now the two polygons matches. Which one would you say represents the reality the better ?

Comment: It depends on how the shapefiles were created! If one was digitized in a particular projection, then *when displayed in that projection* it will be as accurate as the digitization process could make it, *regardless of how coarsely segmented it might be.*  This is an issue that ultimately can be decided only by referring to metadata and having a clear understanding of what you are trying to accomplish and what changes might be made to your data during the process.

Comment: Because you created the 200 m squares with a script they are absolutely accurate in UTM. Therefore big rectangle densified to share the same vertices is better.

Comment: @user30184 I came here to answer it but I see that it is answered in the comments already. May want to move it to a real answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: What scale are these being viewed at?

Comment: Please decide which of ArcMap, QGIS and OGR you wish to ask about in this particular question.  That way we can delve deeper into precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck with that software.  You can always ask about another software in a separate question.